# Jquery window scroll / resize works on bind, not on live

Tags: scroll, live, jquery

So I have an advanced search form, and when you scroll down the results, the search results summary sticks to the top of the page as you scroll using the 'sometimes fixed' code described here - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1810-Creating-A-Sometimes-Fixed-Position-Element-With-jQuery.htm

This all works very nicely, but when some of the form elements are changed, it reloads the whole form, results summary, and results list using AJAX.

I noticed it was using bind to check for the scroll / resize, but the element it needs to effect has obviously been replaced with AJAX, so I changed it to live. This didnt work, on further digging I found out that initially live() only supported certain events, and then was made to work on all events, including custom ones, so why does it still not seem to be working with scroll?

> In jQuery 1.3.x only the following JavaScript events (in addition to
>   custom events) could be bound with .live(): click, dblclick, keydown,
>   keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and
>   mouseup. As of jQuery 1.4 the .live() method supports custom events as
>   well as all JavaScript events that bubble. As of jQuery 1.4.1 even
>   focus and blur work with live (mapping to the more appropriate,
>   bubbling, events focusin and focusout). As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover
>   event can be specified (mapping to mouseenter and mouseleave, which,
>   in turn, are mapped to mouseover and mouseout).

Have tried it with jQuery 1.4.1, 1.5.1, 1.6.2 and no joy. Am I doing something stupid, or is what I am trying to do just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasnt looking likely I would get an easy solution...

So I rewrote the way the search script worked so that the 'sometimes fixed' div wasnt regenerated by ajax, and it loaded the form, results summary, and results directly into their divs